# What is the Hessian of $(\min(0, A) ) ^ 2$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

Suppose I have a matrix $A \in R^{m \times n}$. I would like to know the Hessian of $\min(0, A)^2$. I have computed the gradient which is $2 \min(0,A)$ (am I right ?) but I am stuck in finding the Hessian.

EDIT : After reflexion, I would say it is a diagonal matrix with $H(i,i)=1$ iif $A_i < 0$ (where $H$ is a square matrix of size $mn$ and we suppose that $A$ has been vectorized)

Comment: seems like you missed the square in the body of the question

Comment: @pointguard0 Updated, thanks ! I also edited by saying what I thought it was

Comment: @pointguard0 Am I right ?

Comment: What is your definition of $\min(0,A)$ ? In general, a minimum has no derivative. What is $A_i$ ?

Comment: @loupblanc $min(0,A)$ is $0$ for all the positive elements in matrix $A$ and $A_{i,j}$ if $A_{i,j}<0$. Edited for $A_i$ (actually, vectorized form of the matrix $A$)

Comment: @loupblanc Btw, why a $\min$ function wouldn't have a derivative ? Relu has a derivative, right ?